# I keep getting a variable uninitialized error when calling a function that is asking for user input

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int numofEmployees();
int daysMissed(int);
int AverageMissed(int, int);
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to employee absentee calculator!" << endl;
    int numEmployees = numofEmployees();

    int Missed = daysMissed(numEmployees);

    double misAverage = AverageMissed(numEmployees, Missed);

    cout << "There are " << numEmployees << " in the company.  They have missed " << Missed << " days total.  On average, they have missed " << misAverage << " days." << endl;

    return 0;
}
int numofEmployees() {
    cout << "How many employees are in your company? ";
    int employees;
    cin >> employees;
    while (employees < 1) {
        cout << "Employee count must 1 or greater!" << endl;
    }
    return employees;
}
int daysMissed(int numEmployees) {
    int Absence, totAbsence = 0;
    for (int i = numEmployees; i < numEmployees; i++) {
        cout << "How many days has each employee missed this passed year? ";
        cin >> Absence;
        totAbsence += Absence;
    }
    while (Absence < 0) {
        cout << "Values entered must be positive numbers!" << endl;
        cin >> Absence;
    }
    return totAbsence;
}

int AverageMissed(int numEmployees, int Missed){
    double Average;
    Average = double(numEmployees) / double(Missed);
    return Average;
}
```

This code is being used to calculate the average number of employee absences by way of using three functions.  The second function is not working correctly as it is not being called properly by the main.  This is for a school assignment.

Comment: `int Absence` -- What happens if the number of employees is 0?  The compiler doesn't know any information outside that function w.r.t the number of employees that are passed.

Comment: There is a validation statement in the first function that makes sure that the number of employees can't be less than one.

Comment: Read my comment.  What if I was a bad boy and called your `daysMissed` function with 0 employees?  Also, you really should post where you are getting this warning, but I suspect it is in the `daysMissed` function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.  That function can't be called with 0 employees as it takes the answer from the first function as its input.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function can't be called"?  The function *can* be called -- you just didn't write the call to it.  That's what the compiler warning is all about -- potential errors.  It is a benefit that the compiler can detect this.  In any event, the loop is never executed since it is written incorrectly.  Look at it closely.

Comment: Ok... How is it written incorrectly?  if it not for (initialization, iteration, update)?

Comment: `for (int i = numEmployees; i < numEmployees; i++)` -- How many times will that loop iterate?  Assume for the sake of argument, `numEmployees` is 10.

Comment: For as long as i is less than the number of employees.

Comment: `for ( i = 10; i < 10; ++i)` -- See something wrong with this?  This loop will never iterate -- that's basically what you wrote.

Comment: I see your point now.  Does it need to be equal to absence then?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; ++i)`

Comment: Ok cool.  Any reason why it doesn't ask for the user to input the number of days that each employee has been absent?

Comment: Still because it never iterates, read comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `daysMissed` - if `numEmployees` is <= 0, then `Absense` will be uninitialized.  But, you say, "I check that in `numofEmployees`" - the problem is that the compiler doesn't do that sort of whole-program analysis before issuing these warnings.

There is another problem: `daysMissed` is wrong (twice).  If there are two employees, and I enter -2 and 1, there will be no error for the negative number.  If on the other hand, if I enter 1 and -2, *you never correct* `totAbsence`.  You would be much better off writing a little function which reads a number >= some limit in a loop, and keeps prompting until given the correct value.  Something like:

```
int read(const char* prompt, const char* err_prompt, int limit) {
    cout << prompt << endl;
    for(;;) {
        int result;
        cin >> result;
        if (result >= limit) {
            return result;
        }
        cout << err_prompt << endl;
    }
}
```

Then `daysMissed` becomes much pleasanter to write - and you can use the same function to read the number of employees (which will go into an infinite loop at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

You should also validate a division by zero plus change the return type.

```
double AverageMissed(int numEmployees, int Missed){

if (Missed > 0) return double(numEmployees) / Missed;
return 0;
```

}

by the way, there is no need to cast both operands in the division (/). Casting one of them will be enough to return a double type.